# kyverno policy can't get a variable value

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, policy

I am working on kyverno version **1.10.3** (deployed on EKS ver v1.25.12) and i deployed a policy called **require-pdb** to enforce the creation of PDBs. The policy definition can be found on the kyverno official website https://kyverno.io/policies/other/rec-req/require-pdb/require-pdb/

The issue is related to one namesapce **ONLY** let's call it **application-console**. The policy is facing an issue to retrieve the value of the variable called **pdb_count** (please check the definition in the link above)

Checking the logs of **kyverno-reports-controller** i found the following:

```
I1017 12:59:47.193483       1 rule.go:233] autogen "msg"="processing rule" "rulename"="require-pdb"
I1017 12:59:47.194268       1 vars.go:376] engine.validate "msg"="variable substituted" "new.kind"="Deployment" "new.name"="app-licensemgmt" "new.namespace"="application-console" "path"="" "policy.apply"="All" "policy.name"="require-pdb" "policy.namespace"="" "rule.name"="require-pdb" "value"=2 "variable"="{{ request.object.spec.replicas }}"
I1017 12:59:47.195934       1 vars.go:376] DefaultContextLoaderFactory "msg"="variable substituted" "path"="/jmesPath" "value"={"app.company.com/component":"compute","app.company.com/instance":"app-licensemgmt","app.company.com/managed-by":"helm","app.company.com/name":"app-licensemgmt","app.company.com/owned-by":"team","app.company.com/part-of":"application-console","app.company.com/repository":"company-charts","app.company.com/slack":"company-slack","chart":"app-licensemgmt-0.9.40","com.company.application":"app","com.company.owner":"team-config","com.company.service":"licensemgmt","heritage":"Helm","release":"app-licensemgmt"} "variable"="{{request.object.spec.template.metadata.labels}}"
I1017 12:59:47.196809       1 vars.go:376] DefaultContextLoaderFactory "msg"="variable substituted" "path"="/urlPath" "value"="application-console" "variable"="{{request.namespace}}"
I1017 12:59:47.210289       1 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.20.0.1:443/apis/policy/v1/namespaces/application-console/poddisruptionbudgets 200 OK in 13 milliseconds
I1017 12:59:47.210791       1 apiCall.go:104] DefaultContextLoaderFactory "msg"="executed APICall" "len"=93905 "method"="GET" "name"="pdb_count" "path"="/apis/policy/v1/namespaces/application-console/poddisruptionbudgets"
I1017 12:59:47.211433       1 vars.go:376] DefaultContextLoaderFactory "msg"="variable substituted" "path"="" "value"={"app.company.com/component":"compute","app.company.com/instance":"app-licensemgmt","app.company.com/managed-by":"helm","app.company.com/name":"app-licensemgmt","app.company.com/owned-by":"team","app.company.com/part-of":"application-console","app.company.com/repository":"company-charts","app.company.com/slack":"company-slack","chart":"app-licensemgmt-0.9.40","com.company.application":"app","com.company.owner":"team-config","com.company.service":"licensemgmt","heritage":"Helm","release":"app-licensemgmt"} "variable"="{{request.object.spec.template.metadata.labels}}"
E1017 12:59:47.213730       1 deferred.go:42] DefaultContextLoaderFactory "msg"="failed to load data" "error"="failed to store data for APICall: failed to apply JMESPath items[?label_match(spec.selector.matchLabels, `{\"app.company.com/component\":\"compute\",\"app.company.com/instance\":\"app-licensemgmt\",\"app.company.com/managed-by\":\"helm\",\"app.company.com/name\":\"app-licensemgmt\",\"app.company.com/owned-by\":\"team\",\"app.company.com/part-of\":\"application-console\",\"app.company.com/repository\":\"helm-charts\",\"app.company.com/slack\":\"company-slack\",\"chart\":\"app-licensemgmt-0.9.40\",\"com.company.application\":\"app\",\"com.company.owner\":\"team-config\",\"com.company.service\":\"licensemgmt\",\"heritage\":\"Helm\",\"release\":\"app-licensemgmt\"}`)] | length(@) for context entry pdb_count: Invalid type for: <nil>, expected: []jmespath.JpType{\"object\"}" "name"="pdb_count"
I1017 12:59:47.214034       1 vars.go:46] engine.validate "msg"="Variable substitution failed in preconditions, therefore nil value assigned to variable,  \"pdb_count\" " "new.kind"="Deployment" "new.name"="app-licensemgmt" "new.namespace"="application-console" "policy.apply"="All" "policy.name"="require-pdb" "policy.namespace"="" "rule.name"="require-pdb"
```

The error pointed in the logs above is:

```
pdb_count: Invalid type for: <nil>, expected: []jmespath.JpType{\"object\"}"
```

and i couldn't find why it is nil ?

Part of the definition of the deployment

```
  spec:
    replicas: 4
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        com.company.application: app
        com.company.service: licensemgmt
        release: app-licensemgmt
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app.company.com/component: compute
          app.company.com/instance: app-licensemgmt
          app.company.com/managed-by: helm
          app.company.com/name: app-licensemgmt
          app.company.com/owned-by: team
          app.company.com/part-of: application-console
          app.company.com/repository: company-charts
          app.company.com/slack: company-slack
          chart: app-licensemgmt-0.9.40
          com.company.application: app
          com.company.owner: team-config
          com.company.service: licensemgmt
          heritage: Helm
          release: app-licensemgmt
```

Part of the definition of the PDB

```
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 20%
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      com.company.application: app
      release: app-licensemgmt
```

So briefly:

- The issue of non getting the variable value affects only the resources (deploy/sts) on one namespace (the others ns are not affected)
- The variable in question is **pdb_count**
- Deploying the deploy and its PDB (definition above) are working fine when the policy is not deployed
- I could not find why kyverno is returning **nil** for the **pdb_count** variable ???

Waiting for your help and ideas to debug !

Answer (score 0):

If this hasn't been resolved by now, I'd suggest either filing an issue, a discussion, or a Slack thread in the Kyverno channel on the Kubernetes workspace.

Comment: Hello @Chip Zoller, yes there is thread in kyvern slack channel https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/CLGR9BJU9/p1697814577068869

Comment: Have you logged the requested issue?